# Multi-level reorderable lists?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm building an internal tool to manage our tasks as we have a unique workflow.

I am trying to make a reorderable list that can be nested and reordered on multiple levels, and I am having a difficult time figuring out how to make it work.

The requirements are:

- Be able to reorder tiles within the same level, solved by ReorderableListView.
- Be able to nest tiles within tiles, i.e: create child-tiles by moving them positionally on top of the parent-tiles (i.e: slightly to the right would nest the child-tile instead of position it below/above).

I found a package called drag_and_drop_lists on pub.dev, but it's constrained to being two levels deep, but I want to be able to do this to at least 4 or 5 levels deep.

One idea is to use Draggable class on each tile in a listview, and create an invisible upper layer widget using the Stack class, which is an invisible ListView consisting of rows. Within the rows, there would be widgets equal to the level of the issue it's above, plus 1 (to allow for nesting a new level deeper). However, this did not seem to work.